# Windows server event log has several thousand print errors

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, event-viewer

I'm managing a Windows 2012R2 Server, and when I looked in the event log, I saw about 30,000 errors.

They look like this:

```
Process: PrinterDCA.Service
Level: Error
Process ID: 1196
Thread ID: 20
```

The source is the PrintFleet Enterprise.

How can I find out what's causing the errors? Note that I'm not necessarily looking for the solution, just pointing me in the direction of solving this problem would be helpful as well.

(if I click on Event Log Online Help, it gives me a Microsoft Surface ad)

Comment: Do you have some sort of printer software installed on this machine? What printers are defined on this machine and what are all the printer drivers you have installed on this machine? If the printer configuration is not important for this machine, I'd wipe all printers and drivers from the machine, stop the spooler service, delete any pending print jobs, and then see what's crackin' in the event log. Just a quick guess with no Googling but you should search more.

Comment: Yes, this server is the print server for my company, so the printer configuration is kind of important. Several printers are installed, and all of them are working properly. They are distributed by a group policy, could this be the issue?

Comment: Uh... I would say it is relevant absolutely since it's a printer service issue or whatever with maybe Kyocera or Konica Minolta but see https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/service/Technical_Support/faq/faq_details.L3ByaW50ZXJfbXVsdGlmdW5jdGlvbmFscy9mYXEva3lvZmxlZXRtYW5hZ2VyX19kYXRh.html. I would say look for the latest drivers for applicable models or ensure you have the latest management software installed or check the web site of the manufacturer bug notes for the version, or reach out to the printer company if it's leased and this is software to send them stats for billing, etc.

Comment: What type of printers do you have installed on this machine? Are the drivers updated or do you have management software or are these leased with some software package being required to run on the server or what? Perhaps it's a scan client you installed on the server for advanced features, etc. with the model printers. Hard to say but maybe these comments will ring a bell, but it you lease printers and feel it's related to their drivers or software, I would MAKE their techs provide support to resolve or explain the issue, etc. or have them open ticket with their software vendor. Give more info.

Comment: Like any service on any computer. Try right click on "Computer" > "Manage" > "Services and Applications" > "Services". Then choose the "Printer DCA" Service. Right click going to properties, select the Recovery tab and choose options to recover the service.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work since it's Windows Server. Clicking on Manage opens Server Manager, which doesn't have a Services and Applications.